# In what sense do we use "carry a torch for"?

Tags: phrases, formality

In what sense do we use "carry a torch for"?
Can it be used as a formal, or is it informal?

Comment: Wiktionary answers this quite well already: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carry_a_torch_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is informal and it basically means that someone has a crush, or has unfulled desires for someone else.

> Joe carried a torch for Sue for years before finally getting the courage up to ask her out on a date.

or

> Despite a bad break up in High School, Dave still carries a torch for Lisa.